# YANG, leaf must be unique in a list

Tags: xpath, ietf-netmod-yang

I cant figure out how to create a "must" for a leaf that makes it unique in a list.

This is list with a leaf in it, this leaf may not have the same value as any other leaf in this list.

Example of code:

```
list myList {
  key name;

  leaf name {
    type uint32;
  }

  container myContainer {

    leaf myLeaf {
      type uint32;
    }
    must "count(/myList/myContainer/myLeaf = .) > 1" { //Dont know how to create this must function.
      error-message "myLeaf needs to be unique in the myList list";
    }

  }

}
```

So i want myLeaf to trigger the error-message if there already exist an element in myList with the current value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the list's `unique` keyword for that purpose, no need to bash you head against `must` expressions. It takes one or more space separated schema node identifiers in its argument.

```
    list myList {
      key name;
      unique "myContainer/myLeaf";

      leaf name {
        type uint32;
      }

      container myContainer {

        leaf myLeaf {
          type uint32;
        }

      }

    }
```

If you really want a `must` to handle this (which you shouldn't) you could do something like:

```
    leaf myLeaf {
      must "count(/myList/myContainer/myLeaf[current()=.])=1";
      type uint32;
    }
```

The `current()` XPath function returns the leaf being checked (the initial context node), while `.` stands for `self::node()` and applies to whatever you selected (current XPath context node set).

Also note: a `must` constraint represents an assertion - it MUST evaluate to `true()`, otherwise an instance is considered invalid. Your `> 1` condition would therefore achieve the opposite of what you require.